# Javascript to check if positive

Tags: javascript, function

Javascript function:

```
function checkPos1(){
    var x =  parseInt(document.getElementById('qty1').value);
    if (x < 0)
    {
    alert("Quantity field must contain a positive number!");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Form code:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="get">
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonSubtract1()" name="subtract1" value="-
"/>
     <input type="text" size="4" id="qty1" name="quantity1" value="0"/>
     <input type="button" onclick="buttonAdd1()" name="add1" value="+"/>
     <input type="submit" onclick="checkPos1()" name="product1" value="Add"/>
   </form>
```

Why doesn't this function work? I am trying to make sure the text value manually entered by a customer is a positive integer before it is allowed to submit.

Comment: Have u print the value of x to console? What did u get?

Comment: FYI, zero is neither negative nor positive. Looks like you are truly after a _nonnegative_ number.

Comment: How do I check to make sure that x is an integer?

Comment: To filter out non-numbers, use `!(x>0)` instead of `x<0`.

Comment: @user3691334 Since `x` is the value returned by `parseInt`, you will either have an integer returned or `NaN` (not-a-number). You can test this using `isNaN(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the value being a number or alphabet, you use the built-in feature of JavaScript

```
if(x.isNaN()) {
   /* place the second code in this body */
}
```

You need this

```
if (x < 0) {
    // if less than 0; negative;
    alert("Quantity field must contain a positive number!");
    return false;
} else {
    // if greater than 1; positive;
    alert("Value was positive");
    return false;
}
```

You're not having any block to detect the positive integer by the user that is why its not showing anything at all. I have included a statement and then it would alert the user if the number provided was a positive.

For more on `isNaN` function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: This used with window.event.preventDefault(); works thanks! But how do I check for non numbers?

Comment: For that you use a method known as `NaN` Not a number, you can use this: `if(x.isNan()) { }` this would check whether the value is a number or alphabet characters...

Answer (score 1):

`return false` at the end of an event handler is a jquery convention to stop the chain of event handlers.  Without jquery you should call `preventDefault` method of the event.
Try this:

```
function checkPos1(){
    var x =  parseInt(document.getElementById('qty1').value);
    if (x < 0)
    {
        alert("Quantity field must contain a positive number!");
        window.event.preventDefault();  // <--- stop default handling
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for that `return`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onclick="checkPos1();"` rather than `onclick="checkPos1()"`
and check wheter `x` is carrying any value or not to console.

Comment: How do I check for non numbers?

Comment: simply `alert` the value of `x` before checking the condition. like `alert( x );`

Answer (score 0):

Use 
<form onSubmit="checkPos1();">

Instead of onClick action on submit button.